# React weird state change behavior

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I'm currently writing a React app. I just outsourced my logic into separate files and today I wanted to outsource code, that updates the title of the header. Every route should be able to give my App.js a route name and a title for the header.

When I do this:

```
const useRoute = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({route: "", headerRouteName: ""});

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("(2)", state);
  }, []);

  const setActiveRoute = (route, headerRouteName) => {
    setState({route: route, headerRouteName: headerRouteName});
    console.log("(1)", state);
  }

  return {setActiveRoute, state};
};

export default useRoute;
```

and a in one route:

```
  const {setActiveRoute, state} = useRoute()

  useEffect(() => {
    setActiveRoute("login", "Login");
  }, []);
```

and in App.js

```
  const {setActiveRoute, state} = useRoute()
  const {route, headerRouteName} = state

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("route:", route, headerRouteName);
  }, [route, headerRouteName]);
```

my chrome console gives back these values:

```
Navigated to http://localhost:3000/
[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
(2) {route: "", headerRouteName: ""}
(1) {route: "", headerRouteName: ""}
(2) {route: "", headerRouteName: ""}
route:
```

My route seems to be updated but doesn't get any values.
The weird thing is: When I put in strings directly like this:

```
const useRoute = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({route: "", headerRouteName: ""});

  useEffect(() => {
    setState({route: "route", headerRouteName: "headerRouteName"});
    console.log("(2)", state);
  }, []);

  const setActiveRoute = (route, headerRouteName) => {
    console.log("(1)", state);
  }

  return {setActiveRoute, state};
};

export default useRoute;
```

chrome gives back:

```
Navigated to http://localhost:3000/
[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
(2) {route: "", headerRouteName: ""}
(1) {route: "", headerRouteName: ""}
(2) {route: "", headerRouteName: ""}
route:  
route: route headerRouteName
```

The route gets updated twice and on the second time, the values are in the state.
I want the first variant to work so I can dynamically set the header title.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I'm new to React, so I'm sorry if my question is not the best one, but I did search for an answer, but the "React did not update immediately" threads don't seem to work for me...

Comment: it would be better if you can upload your code somewhere online.

Comment: From your custom hook you are exposing ```return {setActiveRoute, state};``` but in your component you are accessing ```const {getActiveRoute, state} = useRoute()```, Is that intentional ?

Comment: Why you are not using `getActiveRoute` to set the values and expecting to set dynamic values?

Comment: ``getActiveRoute`` is unused, in my route I use ``setActiveRoute`` to set the state.

Comment: you are not using setActiveRoute to set the state dynamically

Comment: Why that? I call setActiveRoute() in one of my routes and the state gets changed. Or did I make a mistake in logic thinking?

Comment: Oh sry, there is something missing... I'll edit it so you see the part where I use ``setActiveRoute``.

Comment: I added the function call of ``setActiveRoute`` in a route.